# Can an entity appear more than once on an EER diagram?

Tags: database-diagrams

I am modeling a database that is a bit complex, and I am having some issues to draw a clean diagram representation of it. Especifically, there is an entity "A" that is a part of many relationships and agregations, and it would be nice to draw more than one rectangle for entity "A" so that every such rectangle is part of only one agregation. This would make the diagram much cleaner and easier to understand. Does this violate the standart notation of EER diagrams? Is there a place where I can find detailed norms for EER diagrams?

In other words, I want to draw more than once entity "A" on a diagram. Is this allowed?

Comment: There's no diagram police that would disallow you drawing anything on your diagram, including duplicate entities and cute kittens. The question is, would the people viewing your diagram understand what you mean?

Comment: I'm addition to what mustaccio said, it may also be a sign that your diagram is too complex for a single diagram and you should refactor parts of it into separate smaller diagrams where entity `A` may appear across multiple diagrams.